# calculate Inception Score and FID in GAN

Tags: neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, gan, transposed-convolution

Do we calculate Inception Score and Fréchet Inception Distance (FID) on the images generated by generator in parallel during training ? Or do we save the images generated by the generator and later calculate the score ?

Comment: this is just an implementation detail

Comment: @shimao I have been following https://www.kaggle.com/riyueguanghua/gan-text-to-image-102flowers-rieyuguanghua this repo in kaggle . How do I calculate the inception score in the repo ?